# Wordpress sort custom field integer by DESC and decimal by ASC

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to sort integer by DESC then decimal by ASC for a single custom field?

I have a custom post type with a custom field called "Order". The values stored in Order are integers and decimals: 01, 02, 03, 03.01, 03.02, 03.03, 04 etc. where decimal values are sub topics of integer values (see examples below).

If I sort "Order" in `DESC` order I get:

```
04 Vans
03.03 Vauxhall
03.02 Nissan
03.01 Honda
03 Cars
02 Buses
01 Bicycles
```

Whereas I want any decimal values sub sorted in `ASC` order as follows:

```
04 Vans
03 Cars
03.01 Honda
03.02 Nissan
03.03 Vauxhall
02 Buses
01 Bicycles
```

I've seen I can solve this with two custom fields but I would prefer only having to update one field unless its so complicated its not worth it.

[Additional information following comments below]

I'm currently retrieving the content with the following WP_Query:

```
<?php
$args=array(
 'post_type' => 'vehicleposts',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'meta_key' => 'Order',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
 'order' => 'DESC',
 'nopaging' => true // Disable post limit per page
);
$customQuery = null;
$customQuery = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php if ( $customQuery->have_posts() ) while ($customQuery->have_posts() ) : $customQuery->the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'vehicle', 'posts' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

As well as being used for sort order the value of "Order" is being displayed on the pages as a numeral. Please feel free to correct me if I've omitted any information you need to answer.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you retrieving this data via a WP_Query request? Is this a $wpdb query? What format does the data need to be in for it to be useable?

Comment: Is that more helpful now? I've added my WP_Query and the way the value is displayed.

Comment: Much better, ta. Just allows people to see the structure of the data that you are pulling in.

Comment: Personally, ease of implementation, I'd make the sub items children of the main items, then use your query to pull in the parents, and inside the template pull in each child underneath that. Seems the simplest method, instead of having to build an array of the posts, sort by the stuff before the decimal, get everything after the decimal, sort by that as a sub-array, then output that to your template.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful, I was unaware of parent child relationships for posts so I learned something new. You answered the question for me when you recommended not trying to parse the custom field into two values. In the end I added a second custom field called "Sub order" and sorted by both as I already knew how to do it and it only took a couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my comment above to @ThallerThanYall. Following his advice I decided not to attempt a solution by parsing a single custom field and just added a second field for sub order. That makes it possible to order the posts by order and suborder. I'm posting the solution in case its useful for anyone else.

The arguments for the WP_Query to do this are as follows. Most of this is taken from the last solution on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in the Wordpress Codex but that example doesn't show how to declare the values are numerical not strings for which you use `'type' => 'Numeric'` in the meta_query.

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'vehicleposts',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'vehicle_order' => array(
      'key' => 'Order',
      'type' => 'Numeric'
    ),
    'vehicle_suborder' => array(
      'key' => 'Sub order',
      'type' => 'Numeric'
    ),
  ),
  'orderby' => array(
    'vehicle_order' => 'DESC',
    'vehicle_suborder' => 'ASC'
  ),
  'nopaging' => true // Disable post limit per page
);
?>
```